# Kallyas theme in Wordpress add slider php code

Tags: wordpress

I have installed a slider plugin called Revolution Slider for my Kallyas theme. I need to add the php line code so that I get my slider working. Can anyone help about where should I exactly place that line?

Comment: What page do you want it shown on?

Comment: I want the slider to show in all pages.

Comment: Really? Do you want us to Google what plugin is this and then read its documentation and then tell you how it works? Ok.

Comment: I can't get that documentation, it'll be nice if you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a three ways to insert into the theme and the slider appears in your pages:

1. For all the pages: `<?php putRevSlider( "slider_alias" ) ?>`
2. For show only on homepage: `<?php putRevSlider("slider_alias","homepage") ?>`
3. For show on certain pages use: `<?php putRevSlider("slider_alias","2,10") ?>`. The numbers here are de ID of the pages.

Here the [full documentation](http://themepunch.com/codecanyon/revolution_wp/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

We would have to have see your header.php file / or see how the theme is structured in order to see where the best place would be to insert the PHP snippet provided by revslider.

Are you aware that you can use shortcode inside of your pages / posts instead of using the PHP snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If it is to appear on every page you can add

to the header, footer or content pages (depending on where on the page you want to put it (and changing shortcodeXYZ to whatever the shortcode is).